# Redux Error: You are currently using minified code outside of NODE_ENV

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, expo

the full error is:"You are currently using minified code outside of NODE_ENV === "production". This means that you are running a slower development build of redux. ..."

I already tried installing webpack and setting the mode to "production" in the webpack.config.js file but it didn't work. I have a running project with redux and react-redux installed. As soon as I add the import statement to the App.js:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
```

it throws the error. I use expo for my app and ideally I don't want to use webpack. According to the Redux documentation webpack is not necessary. 
Why does it throw the error?

App.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import { AppFontLoader } from "./AppFontLoader";
import { Drawer } from "./Navigation";
//import { createStore } from 'redux' //uncommenting this line throws the error

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppFontLoader>
        <Drawer />
      </AppFontLoader>
    );
  }
}
```